# MiKTeX and new package signchart

Tags: miktex

I noticed that the 2/2/2016 update of the MiKTeX package repository has a new package, `signchart`. I updated my MiKTeX distribution, but the `signchart` package is unavailable.

Is there a delay between the package repository update and having the package available to install on-the-fly?

Comment: I'd guess that there usually is. For TeX Live, I believe the turnaround time is about 24 hours. (I have `signchart` for 29 January 2016; and `tlmgr` doesn't list any updates yet available.) I can't say anything reliably intelligent about MiKTeX, however.

Comment: On-the-fly will only work if you first synchronize the package manager(s) to update the local package name database.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388

Comment: I decided to agree with the close votes because the OP states in his answer that the problem was just a slow mirror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem: my impatience.

I had synchronized my package manager, as @ulrike-fischer recommends, but on February 2, the `signchart` package wasn't appearing in my database.

I now realize that the MiKTeX update hadn't propagated to the particular mirror I used to update. The next day I chose a different mirror, and there appeared `signchart`!